# How can I show asterisks instead of characters when a textbox reaches maximum length?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox whose `maxlength` attribute is 13. When the user reachers 13, I must hide all the characters and show asterisk symbols (*).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keypress() function. Everytime the user type a character, you check the length of the string. Then you can trigger another function if it is longer than 13 characters

Comment: How do I make the string appear as asteriks?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use keyup() than keypress(), since it will return the current length of the input. keypress will be "one step after"

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if( $this).val().length > 13 )
        $(this).val('*');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't either change the 1st 13 characters to asterisks _or_ keep the real value.

Comment: @Archer Oh, missed the keep value part, but `data()` can be used for that as someone mentioned. As far as the 13 * are concerned, i thought he would figure something out himself :)

Answer (score 0):

See this:

**HTML:**

```
Input: <input type="text" maxlength="13" id="myInput"/>

<input type="password" maxlength="13" id="myInputHide" class="hidden">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
       $(".hidden").hide();                        //Hide the asterik field initially
       $("#myInput").keyup(                        //Handle the keyup on the input field
           function() {
               if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
                   $(this).hide();
                   $("#" + this.id + "Hide").show().val($(this).val());
               }
           }
       );

        $("#myInputHide").keyup(                        //Handle the keyup on the asterik field
           function() {
               if($(this).val().length != $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
                   $(this).hide();
                   $("#" + this.id.replace(/Hide$/,"")).show().val($(this).val());
               }
           }
       );

    }

);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43KaL/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var count = 0;
var maxLength = 4; //or you can gte your maxlength attributes value
$("#yourInputId").keyup(function() {
   count++;
   if(count > maxLength) {
      var changVal = $(this).val();
      var newVal = "";
     for(var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
         newVal += changVal.charAt(i).replace(changVal.charAt(i), "*");
     }
     $(this).val(newVal); 
   }
});
```

And yes you need to fine tune it